# Передача аргумента классу по-средствам вызова "... db:seed --class=MyClass"

Tags: php, laravel

Интересует возможность реализации передачи переменной в класс при вызове из командной строки

```
php artisan db:seed --class=MyClass
```

Либо при вызове из файлов, по сути тоже самое..

```
Artisan::call('db:seed', [
    'class' => 'MyClass'
]);
```

Существуют ли какие нибудь встроенные возможности? Или что надо сделать для этого?

На сколько безобразным действием будет редактирование и внесение необходимой функции в SeedCommand.php?

Comment: Что именно вы хотите? Сделать свою команду или с сидером что-то?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan, я хочу в команде передать переменную в 'MyClass', например "php artisan db:seed --class=MyClass --arg=3"

Comment: Зачем ещё аргументы?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan, ну например сколько строк заполнить в бд faker'ом, или это делается иначе?

Comment: Сделайте несколько сидеров, а вообще это странно, обычно сидер выполняют в начала и всё